# Standard HTML & CSS to wordpress page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

I created a webpage in Standard HTML and CSS and everything looks / works exactly how I want it too.
Now I need it to appear as it is on a wordpress site (http://www.texasenergyessentials.com/). I already created a template page and can see it in the template select in the wordpress "add new page" window. I was hoping I could just select the template and leave the text editor blank but that doesn't seem to be the case. All I get is a completely un-formatted page that says welcome guest.

What is the easiest way to get https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8545681 to work on the aforementioned wordpress site?  ?

Thanks!

P.S. Please don't link any codex files I just spent 2 hours digging around in them :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to read and understand how http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop works

Install this theme https://code.google.com/p/wordpress-naked/ and try to work your way to the desired theme by editing theme files. That will be much easier.

Comment: from the question: `P.S. Please don't link any codex files I just spent 2 hours digging around in them :(`

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestions.

I'm familiar with how the loop works but I don't see how that helps me here. I don't want to pull existing headers or footers

Unfortunately I'm stuck using the theme already installed as it's not my site to tamper with at that level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem can be understood by reading the template hierarchy:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
(especially check the visual overview)

If you name your file page-[insert-page-id-here].php Wordpress will use it for the page you've created. Get your page id by editing the page and looking it up in the url.